# Father was used to carrying luggage anyway. Is 'used to' used as helping verb?

Tags: modal-verbs

I've come across the above sentence in a story. The structure "used to + present participle" puzzles me a bit. please explain its meaning and usage.

Comment: Did you try looking the expression "used to" in a dictionary?  If so, was there something you didn't understand, that we can help with?

Comment: It is given as "used to+v1" in the dictionary.  But it is "used to+noun equivalent" in the given context. Isn't it? So it is brought to the perusal of linguistics here for clarification. Thanks for your swift response.

Comment: “used to” means “accustomed to” here.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining your concern.  Take a look at this: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/used+to

Comment: I came to know that "used to" is an adjective followed by a noun in this context.

Comment: "Used" is an adjective, with the PP "to carrying luggage anyway" as its complement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grammar Explanation for "be used to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342176/grammar-explanation-for-be-used-to)

Comment: "Used to" isn't a verb indicating something he once did but does no longer; it's referring to something he was accustomed to doing.  Notice that it's not saying, "Father used to carry luggage"; it's saying, "Father *was* used to carrying luggage," meaning he was "accustomed to" carrying luggage.  You can substitute "accustomed to" for "used to."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Father was used to carrying luggage any way.**

Here **used** is not the helping verb but it is the adjective.It means accustomed to. To is a preposition and so it is followed by an ingform.

This is different from **used to** which we use for past habits.

*I am used to speaking English*

*I used to speak English*

These are different structures and have differences in meaning

The first sentence means that **I am accustomed or habituated to speak English**

The second sentence means that **I spoke in English in the past but now I stopped speaking English**.

Comment: @ChinnabatthinaSivaKumar If you are satisfied with the answer, accept it. That's the best way of expressing your gratitude. You can up-vote as well.

Comment: @ChinnabatthinaSivaKumar In your example "used" is not a verb, but an adjective. Note that the "to" is part of the PP "to carrying luggage anyway" JVL -- sorry but you need to change your answer.