# Why is it correct to say "She hadn't been used to being treated like that" and not "She hadn't been used to be treated like that"?

Tags: grammar, tenses, used-to

I know that we use "To be+used to+gerund" for expressing something that's happening at the moment of speaking. But I don't know how to apply the rule with the sentence above. Do we always use gerund when "used to" is preceded by "to be" ?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Note that with *to be used **to** [something]*, the highlighted word is a ***preposition***, not an "infinitive marker*. But the negated Past Perfect for the primary verb clause is irrelevant to the issue of why the subordinate verb clause uses ***being*** rather than ***be***. It's exactly the same issue with ***She's used to BEING treated like that*** (NOT ***She's used to BE treated like that***).

Comment: Also note that "To be+used to+gerund" has no particular implications for *expressing something that's happening **at the moment of speaking***. Sure - I can say ***I'm used to being ignored*** with "present moment relevance". But I can also say ***I was used to being ignored***, which says nothing at all about whether I'm ***still*** being ignored (and continue to think nothing of it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grammar Explanation for "be used to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342176/grammar-explanation-for-be-used-to)

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

There are two main different types of *to* in English. One of these is the *to* we find in *to*-infinitive constructions (e.g. ***To*** err is human), the other is the directional preposition (e.g. *I drove **to** the farm)*.

The English verb *use(d)* takes a *to*-infinitive as a Complement. The English adjective *used* takes a *to* preposition phrase as a Complement. If we want to use a verb after a preposition such as *to*, we need an *-ing* form of the verb.

The Original Poster's example uses the adjective *used* and therefore we need a *to* preposition phrase using an *-ing* form of the verb. The adjective *used* cannot take a *to*-infinitive as a Complement.

---

**The full story**

**The verb *use(d)***:

There is a defective English verb *use(d)* which describes a situation or habit in the past:

> 1. I used to be a lawyer.

This verb has no present or past participles, and also no present tense form. This verb is completely different from the verb *use* meaning to exploit something. The former is pronounced /ju:s(t)/ and has an unvoiced sibilant, the latter is pronounced/ju:z/ and uses a *voiced* sibilant.

As can be seen from (1), the verb *use(d)* takes *to*-infinitives as  Complements. It cannot take an *-ing* form of the verb:

> 2. *I used to being a lawyer. ( * = ungrammatical)

**The adjective *used:***

There is an English adjective *used*, which means  *accustomed*. Like the adjective *accustomed*, the adjective *used* takes a preposition phrase as a Complement. It cannot take a verb as a Complement:

> 3. *I am used [eat cheese].
> 4. *I became used [eating cheese].
> 5. *I felt used [to eat cheese].
> 6. *He looked used [eat cheese].

More specifically the adjectives *accustomed* and *used* take preposition phrases headed by the preposition *to*. Note that this is not the infinitival particle that we find in infinitival constructions such as *I want **to sing***. Notice as well that this adjective usually appears as the Complement of a so-called linking verb such as *be, seem, feel, look*. [In other words it appears as an ascriptive Predicative Complement]

Now those prepositions which take noun phrases as Complements, such as the prepositions *to* or *of* or *from*, can take *-ing* verb phrases or clauses (also known as gerund-participial clauses) as Complements:

> 7. look forward [to Christmas]
> 8. look forward [to **celebrating**]
> 9. tired [of lessons]
> 10. tired [of **studying**]
> 11. shrank [from his work]
> 12. shrank [from **carrying out his duties**]

Notice that these *-ing* clauses are not Complements of *look*, *tired*, or *shrank*, rather they are Complements of the prepositions *to*, *of* and *from* respectively. If we take a look at the adjectives *used* and *accustomed*, we will see that they work in exactly the same way:

> 13. used [to French food]
> 14. used [to **eating French food**]
> 15. accustomed [to French food]
> 16. accustomed [to **eating French food**]

---

**The Original Poster's question:**

> 17. She hadn't been used [to [being treated like that]].

Because this sentence is quite complicated, it might be difficult to tell whether the item  *used* here, is the verb or the adjective. A good test is to see whether we can substitute in the adjective accustomed *accustomed* instead. If so, this *used* is the adjective, if not then it is the verb:

> 18. She hadn't been accustomed [to [being treated like that].

Although somewhat clunky, this is perfectly grammatical, and the meaning of the sentence is basically the same. This means that we are talking about the adjective *used*. As we have seen above this adjective takes preposition phrases with the preposition *to*. and as we have also seen, if we want to use a verb after a preposition like *to*, we need to use an *ing* form of the verb. We cannot use a plane form of the verb or a *to*-infinitive:

> 19. *I wasn't used [to [eat cheese]].
> 20. *I wasn't used [to [to eat cheese]].

For that reason, the following is also ungrammatical:

> 21. *She hadn't been accustomed [to [be treated like that]].

Comment: Even shorter answer: There are two idioms with _used to_; both are pronounced /yust/, with an /s/, never a /z/. One idiom must occur with an auxiliary _be_, and it means 'accustomed to, familiar with'; it takes a gerund after the _to_ of the idiom: _I'm used to having dinner after 10:00 Mass_. The other idiom does not use _be_, and it means 'did once in the past but don't any longer'; it takes an infinitive after _to_: _I used to have dinner after 10:00 Mass_. The first means that's your current custom; the second one means you no longer do it, though you once did.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, absolutely +1. The first doesn't always occur with *be* though, does it? (*Get, grow, become, seem, appear* etc).

Comment: Thank you for such details. It certainly made things clear for me.

Comment: @Zhao My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

...used to being treated is like,  used to + passive voice of 'treating'.  In 2nd sentence,...used to be treated..., followed the passive form of 'to treat'.

It is more correct to say, One is used to being blamed... than 'one is used to be blamed...The relevance goes to 'ing' form in passive voice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !